# Select data from XML file as table in TSQL

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql

Could someone show me some TSQL to use to query an xml file as if it were a table?

The file is on the server, "C:\xmlfile.xml"

And contains

```
<ArrayOfSpangemansFilter xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <SpangemansFilter>
        <FilterID>1219</FilterID>
        <Name>Fred</Name>
        <Code>510</Code>
        <Department>N</Department>
        <Number>305327</Number>
    </SpangemansFilter>
    <SpangemansFilter>
        <FilterID>3578</FilterID>
        <Name>Gary</Name>
        <Code>001</Code>
        <Department>B</Department>
        <Number>0692690</Number>
    </SpangemansFilter>
    <SpangemansFilter>
        <FilterID>3579</FilterID>
        <Name>George</Name>
        <Code>001</Code>
        <Department>X</Department>
        <Number>35933</Number>
    </SpangemansFilter>
</ArrayOfSpangemansFilter>
```

Example output I am after

```
FilterID    |Name       |Code       |Department             |Number
-------------------------------------------------------------------
1219        |Fred       |510        |N                      |305327
3578        |Gary       |001        |B                      |0692690
3579        |George     |001        |X                      |35933
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
set @xmlData='<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ArrayOfSpangemansFilter xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<SpangemansFilter>
<FilterID>1219</FilterID>
<Name>Fred</Name>
<Code>510</Code>
<Department>N</Department>
<Number>305327</Number>
</SpangemansFilter>
<SpangemansFilter>
<FilterID>3578</FilterID>
<Name>Gary</Name>
<Code>001</Code>
<Department>B</Department>
<Number>0692690</Number>
</SpangemansFilter>
<SpangemansFilter>
<FilterID>3579</FilterID>
<Name>George</Name>
<Code>001</Code>
<Department>X</Department>
<Number>35933</Number>
</SpangemansFilter>
</ArrayOfSpangemansFilter>'


SELECT 
  ref.value('FilterID[1]', 'int') AS FilterID ,
  ref.value('Name[1]', 'NVARCHAR (10)') AS Name ,
  ref.value('Code[1]', 'NVARCHAR (10)') AS Code ,
  ref.value('Department[1]', 'NVARCHAR (3)') AS Department,
  ref.value('Number[1]', 'int') AS Number      
FROM @xmlData.nodes('/ArrayOfSpangemansFilter/SpangemansFilter') 
xmlData( ref )
```

Produces:

```
FilterID    Name       Code       Department Number
----------- ---------- ---------- ---------- -----------
1219        Fred       510        N          305327
3578        Gary       001        B          692690
3579        George     001        X          35933
```

Note: The `[1]` is needed to indicate that you want to select the first value of the sequence since the query may return more than one matched value per row (imagine your XML containing several FilterIDs per SpangemansFilter).

I thought this was useful to know, so I Googled and read many posts until I found [this one.](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-ZA/sqlxml/thread/ed99cfa4-015c-46ee-a7f9-dc49af0a84d0)

**UPDATE**
To load from file:

```
DECLARE @xmlData XML
SET @xmlData = (
  SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET (
    BULK 'C:\yourfile.xml', SINGLE_CLOB
  ) AS xmlData
)
```

SELECT @xmlData

Comment: That's great but you don't specify how to do this from an XML file rather than a @xmlData variable. The file is on the server, "C:\xmlfile.xml"

Answer (score 1):

In my case - the data I was interested in was contained in the node attributes rather than values. Below includes an example of how the attributes can be accessed.

```
DECLARE @xmlData XML
set @xmlData='<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ArrayOfSpangemansFilter xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<SpangemansFilter FilterID="1219" Name="Fred" Code="510" Department="N" Number="305327">
</SpangemansFilter>
<SpangemansFilter FilterID="3578" Name="Gary" Code="001" Department="B" Number="0692690">
</SpangemansFilter>
<SpangemansFilter FilterID="3579" Name="George" Code="001" Department="X" Number="35933">
</SpangemansFilter>
</ArrayOfSpangemansFilter>'


SELECT 
  ref.value('@FilterID', 'int') AS FilterID ,
  ref.value('@Name', 'NVARCHAR (10)') AS Name ,
  ref.value('@Code', 'NVARCHAR (10)') AS Code ,
  ref.value('@Department', 'NVARCHAR (3)') AS Department,
  ref.value('@Number', 'int') AS Number      
FROM @xmlData.nodes('/ArrayOfSpangemansFilter/SpangemansFilter') 
xmlData( ref )
```