# Fetch a value from a column which contains XML

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

How to fetch a value from a column which contains XML in SQL Server?
below is my sample XML column value and the id's can be swap anytime(101,100) or (201,100,101,321).

```
<Questions>
 <item id="101">Yes</item>
 <item id="100">No</item>
</Questions>
```

I want to fetch a value based on Id. Like fetching `Yes` from `id=101`.
Sample code much appreciated.

I tried with below sample, but Unable to retrieve value "Yes"

```
select Y.value('@item[1]','varchar[3]') as valT from tbl_storeXML s cross apply s.Questions.nodes('Questions/item') as X(Y) where e.empId=256 and Y.value('@id','int')=101
```

Please help on this.
Ps. It's not a home work, I am learning handling xml in sql server.

Comment: @DaleK did you mean to post on another question?

Comment: haha yes :) ...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Select data from XML file as table in TSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7649301/select-data-from-xml-file-as-table-in-tsql)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I query a value in SQL Server XML column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10344553/how-can-i-query-a-value-in-sql-server-xml-column)

Comment: As per the question guide, do some research to find out if your question  was asked earlier (which might have your answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use of the `value` is not done correct, you do:

1. `Y.value('@id','int')`

This should be: `Y.value('(@id)[1]','int')`

- round braces around `@id`, see: [docs: value() Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/value-method-xml-data-type?view=sql-server-ver15)

and `Y.value('item[1]','varchar[3]')`.

This should be: `Y.value('(@item)[1]','varchar(3)')`.

- The `@` is removed because `item` is not an attribute
- `varchar` should have round braces, not square braces.

Your *try*, after changes will become:

```
select 
   Y.value('(item)[1]','varchar(3)') as valT 
from tbl_storeXML s 
cross apply s.Questions.nodes('Questions/item') as X(Y) 
where e.empId=256 and Y.value('(@id)','int')=101
```

This is not tested, because I do not have those tables. (I do think `Y.value('(item)[1]','varchar(3)')` might need to be written as `Y.value('(.)[1]','varchar(3)')` )

But the same approach can be seen in this [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=fff150e8932252fec75a9fb3933e836a)

```
DECLARE @xml XML = '<Questions>
 <item id="101">Yes</item>
 <item id="100">No</item>
</Questions>';

select 
  X.y.value('(@id)[1]','VARCHAR(20)') id,
  X.y.value('(.)[1]','VARCHAR(20)') value
from  @xml.nodes('Questions/item') as X(y);
```

output:

| id | value |
| --- | --- |
| 101 | Yes |
| 100 | No |